# The given data was invalid. - how to know what was wrong?

Tags: laravel

I hava a validation rule for each `$row`:

```php
    try {
        $validator = \Validator::make($row, [
            '1' => 'required',
            '2' => 'required',
            '3' => 'required',
            '4' => '',
            '5' => ''
        ])->validate();
    
    } catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Inside catch I get only this text error:

> The given data was invalid.

How to know what was wrong with validation row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ValidationException` [has an `errors()` function](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.html#method_errors) that will list the validation errors.

```
dd($e->errors());
```

should dump them out for viewing.

Comment: I dont see this: `catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) {

                dd($e->errors());

                $this->errors[] = $e->getMessage();

            }`

Comment: Why are you doing `$this->errors`? Don't do that.

Comment: I collect all errors for each row to this varaible in loop

Comment: I have array with indexes, I want to validate all elements of array

Comment: Validation errors are already automatically collected, contained within the ValidationException, and even [passed to your views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#working-with-error-messages). There's no need to store them separately.

Comment: I use API no view presentation

Comment: @AliceMessis If you use Laravel's built-in FormRequest class for validation, it will handle that for you. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation

Answer (score 0):

why your validation rule is empty?

```
'4' => '',
'5' => ''
```

if your field is nullable either remove that from validation rule or add 'nullable'.

Comment: It no needs validations, only first two columns

Comment: The same result, I got message but dont understand what happends